# My database values for the detected QR are not changing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m designing a QR scanner application that reads the generated QR from another application and change its value. The application works correctly and it scans the QR's where the metaDataObj.stringValue is the value of the QR detected. the problem is when i try to change the child value on firebase it doesn’t change. What's wrong with the code?
Attached picture of my database
[image: Database Picture]

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
    messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
    let QRnumber = metadataObj.stringValue ?? ""
    let QRname = ref.child("QRCode")
    QRname.observe(.childAdded, with: { [self] snapshot in
       let detected = snapshot.value as? Int
       if detected == Int(QRnumber){
       snapshot.setValue(true, forKey: "isScanned")
           self.messageLabel.text = "successfuly scanned"
       }
       else{
           messageLabel.text = "not valid QR"

       }
}
```

Comment: Is this a different problem from [the one you posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490942/retrieving-data-from-firebase-qr-application)? If so, can you update *that* question to show how you solved it, so that others can benefit from your experience?

Comment: Yes its different the previous one wasn’t working know theres a problem with the database. I’m deleting the previous one

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your `snapshot` variable is a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot), which doesn't have a `setValue(, forKey:)` method. So I'd expect this code to raise an error about calling a non-existing method.

To get the value of the timestamp in the key of the snapshot:

```
let detected = snapshot.key as? String //  Keys are always strings
```

To get the value of the `isScanned` property of the snapshot:

```
let isScanned = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "isScanned").value as? boolean
```

Comment: i want to update the value of is scanned to true not only read it. Thanks for your collaboration

Comment: i did what you mentioned but the problem is: the code is not entering the if statement i don’t nt know why

Comment: 1) You can't update the value in a snapshot. To update in the database would be something like `snapshot.ref.setValue(....)`. 2) Did you step through the code in a debugger yet? If so, what is the value of `detected` after `let detected = snapshot.key as? String`?

Comment: When i tried to print detected it prints all the Keys which are the numbers of QRCode collection in the picture. I don’t t know if its right to compare like this? I want to check all of the keys if any of them is equal to the detected value update isScanned to true

Comment: Are you sure you are still using `QRname.observe(.childAdded, with: { [self] snapshot in`? Because with that, `snapshot` should be one child node of `QRCode` each time.